# Moving elements with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have tens of thousands XML files that I need to transform into HTML5.

The problem is with the lists and how in XML they are not nested as they need to be in HTML.

Here's how the XML looks like:

```
<list>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <list>
        <item>2.1</item>
        <list>
            <item>2.1.1</item>
            <item>2.1.2</item>
        </list>
        <item>2.2</item>
        <item>2.2</item>
    </list>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</list>
```

And how the HTML should be (i.e. `ul` nested inside `li`):

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1
                <ul>
                    <li>2.1.1</li>
                    <li>2.1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>2.2</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a lot examples that I found here but couldn't get any of them work for me.

Copying elements is working but now moving. And I don't know how to "delete" the original content that was copied.

This is what I now get from my transformation:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul>
            <li>2.1
                <ul>
                    <li>2.1.1</li>
                    <li>2.1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li>2.1.1</li>
                <li>2.1.2</li>
            </ul>
            <li>2.2</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <li>2.1
            <ul>
                <li>2.1.1</li>
                <li>2.1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li>2.1.1</li>
            <li>2.1.2</li>
        </ul>
        <li>2.2</li>
        <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the xslt that I have used:

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::list]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::list[1]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: And your XSLT code? Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="html" version="5.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="list">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | following-sibling::*[1][self::list]"/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the result you posted for the input you posted. But I am not sure if it works with more complex input, you might want to add variations of the input sample.

Comment: Thank you! This one did the trick. I have tested this with a simple XML that I was using for testing but also a more complex XML seems to transform properly.